# Get data from JSONArray

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I'm trying to parse data from my `json` with the following kotlin code:

```
val text = JSONObject(URL(request).readText())
val results = text.getJSONArray("results")
val name = results.getJSONObject(5).getString("name") // org.json.JSONException: Index 5 out of range [0..1)
```

**json**

```
{
    summary: {
    queryType: "NEARBY",
    queryTime: 13,
    numResults: 2,
    offset: 0,
    totalResults: 2,
    fuzzyLevel: 1,
    geoBias: {
        lat: -37.736343,
        lon: 145.152114
        }
    },
    results: [
    {
    type: "POI",
    id: "AU/POI/p0/77255",
    score: -0.38554,
    dist: 385.5365152133808,
    info: "search:ta:0323405846509-AU",
    poi: {
        name: "La Gourmet",
```

However I'm getting the following error on my 3rd line:

```
org.json.JSONException: Index 5 out of range [0..1)
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. I resorted to searching for `name` via index because `.getJSONObject("poi")` doesn't take a `String`. This is also concerning because the data may change so I would prefer to query the `JSON` via `String`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`results` is an array, and your code tries to get the 5th element of the array. You need to get the first element, and then you can get `poi` by name.

```
val text = JSONObject(URL(request).readText())
val results = text.getJSONArray("results")
val result0 = results.getJSONObject(0)
val poi = result0.getJSONObject("poi")
```